# Magento 2 static files not creating mage folder and mixins.js

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, mixins

After upgrading from Magento 2.2.2 to Magento 2.3.3. While generating  static content with command **"php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f"** 
 it updates all the files in pub/static folder except mage folder and files from

> "vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage"

to

> "pub/static/frontend/Theme/Theme_Name/en_US/"

I am using following command

```
php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: check the folder permissions

Comment: Checked folder permissions for pub,static and mage.All folders have 0777 permission. Other static files are generated and copied in static folder

Answer (score 0):

Delete your vendor and run again...

> composer install